# Return coefficients after Pipeline, GridSearch, and Target Transformation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, coefficients

This question has been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856280/return-coefficients-from-pipeline-object-in-sklearn) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375911/how-to-print-estimated-coefficients-after-a-gridsearchcv-fit-a-model-sgdregr). When I try those answers, my error message is that my model has no attribute of `coef`. I use a pipeline, gridsearch, and Target Transformation. I can access the model itself, but my error message is that my model, SGDRegressor has no attribute coef_.

```
cv_inner = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
params = {'model__regressor__penalty':['elasticnet']
            ,'model__regressor__l1_ratio': [0.1,0.3]
            }
mymodel = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                                ('model', TTR(regressor=SGDRegressor(n_jobs=-1),transformer=qt))
                                ])
optimize_hparams = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = mymodel, param_grid=params, n_jobs = -1,
    cv=cv_inner, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
optimize_hparams.fit(X, y)
optimize_hparams.best_estimator_.named_steps['model'].regressor.coef_
# 'SGDRegressor' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

Comment: What does `optimize_hparams.best_estimator_.named_steps['model'].coef_` do?

Comment: In theory it extracts the coefficients from the model. This is what triggers the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TransformedTargetRegressor` attribute `regressor` is the input unfitted estimator.  You want `regressor_`, the fitted regressor.  (Note the documentation says that `regressor` gets cloned prior to fitting, which is why the attribute remains unfitted.)

Comment: always the simplest change with these things